# GitLab CI/CD How to run script on runner if success or fails?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm starting to using GitLab CI/CD for some automation, turns out that I wanted to use WebHooks as described [HERE](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html), unfortunately within the company we don't have this option available.

So I was thinking on making a [cURL POST](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html#POST) request in order to achieve what I wanted using the WebHooks. However I'm not sure in which part of the `gitlab-ci.yml` to put this.

Are there are any [Tags](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/) where I can put the instructions to run the cURL, right before the runner finishes? The idea is to make a POST informing if it has failed or succeeded.

Comment: You want to run the script after all stages ran or after each stage ?

Comment: @AndréRoggeriCampos I want to start with the basics. When everything is finish i want to send a POST to an endpoint with the result "success or failed".

Comment: You can adjust email notifications to notify you about both success and failure of a pipeline [read more](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/notifications.html)

Comment: If you're wanting to make a status page thing, I create SVG badges with [anybadge](https://pypi.org/project/anybadge/). They are `RED` if the job failed. You can get that file using the "raw" url. Example: `BASE_URL/%{project_path}/-/jobs/artifacts/%{default_branch}/raw/badge.svg?job=build`. See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#downloading-the-latest-artifacts